# How to identify if a device (scanner) is local or remote?

Tags: c#, windows-10, remote-desktop, wia, device-manager

**Context:**
I have a C# application that works with a scanner, on a Windows 10 environment.
In some situation, users would, from their local computer, connect to a remote computer that is running the application.
The application shows a list of scanners that are available, both local and remote.
I need the application to be able to identify whether a scanner is local (connected to the computer the user is on) or remote (connected to the computer on which the application is running).

**What I have tried:**
Using the [DeviceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-devicemanager) object from the WIA library, I am able to get a list of properties (DeviceInfo.Properties) from each device connected to the computer.
One property, *PnP ID String*, always displays "&rev" for remote scanners.

Example of PnP ID String for a local scanner:
[image: PnP ID string, local scanner]

For a remote scanner:
[image: PnP ID string, remote scanner]

This behavior has been observed with several scanners from different brands (namely Fujitsu, HP).
The "tsusb-session" string found for the remote scanner looked intersting in the first place but is absent when testing with HP scanners.

Also, one of the properties that is recovered is Remote Device ID, but it is always displayed blank.

Is the "&rev" thing a reliable way to identify a remote device ?
If not, is there an accurate way to do it ?